# how to set cookies as secure flag in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot and completely unaware how it's work . while authenticating the login JSESSIONID is created as cookie . Login code is as below

```
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .loginPage("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/app/**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**", "/favicon.ico", "/").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
```

How to make the cookie have secure flag

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **application.properties** set the following property:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true
```

... or in older versions (before ~**2018**):

```
server.session.cookie.secure=true
```

Answer (score 9):

> Property 'server.session.cookie.secure' is **Deprecated**:
>   Use
>   'server.servlet.session.cookie.secure' instead.

In the **application.properties** put it:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true
```

Comment: this is not working for me. When I look in the browser for this cookie, it still does not have secure flag on.

Comment: Note this is Spring Boot 2.0 setting.