# Spring property for Set Cookie Secure flag not working

Tags: spring, security, header, config

Tried using the below spring properties:

```
server.servlet.session.cookie.http-only=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true
```

Still not able to see secure flag in response header for Set Cookie.

[image]

Comment: Have you got your answer?

Comment: @Ravi are you looking at the page via https?

Comment: @GaborLengyel, yes, I'm looking for https

Comment: Looking for, or testing on? Many backends won't set the cookie as secure if the request was over plain http as it doesn't make sense, the backend would not receive it back anyway.

Comment: @krishan If you are using an older version you have to user `server.session.cookie.secure=true` https://stackoverflow.com/a/47989710/1038268